# Error while coding a multi threaded program with boost library

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have created two threads which would execute a single piece of code parallely.I want to run another method when the two threads have finished execution.I have tried join() and timed_join(),but it is not working.I am using boost thread class.Please find below my code:

Code:

```
A class:
A a;
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&A::method1,&a,s1,e1));//Call method1 using two parameters     s1 and e1.boost bind is used to call class methods
boost::thread t1(boost::bind(&A::method1,&a,s2,e2));//Call method1 using two parameters   s2 and e2.boost bind is used to call class methods.
t.join();
t1.join();
methodToBeExecutedAfterThreadExec();
```

Let me know how to execute a method1 parallely using threads and then i have to call `methodToBeExecutedAfterThreadExec()` method.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:

```
void method1(int start,int end)
{
    vector< vector<string> >::iterator row;
vector<string>::iterator col;
db.onAutoVacuumMode();//Vacuum mode is set to true which eliminates fragmentation
db.startTransaction();//Starts the transaction which does the stuff in a batch wise
for (row = dupViewResults.begin()+start; row != dupViewResults.begin()+end; ++row) {

    std::string filedata=readFileDataInStr(row->at(0));
    int x = boost::lexical_cast<int>( row->at(1) );
    long long int fileCRC32=MurmurHash(filedata.c_str(),x,0);
    std::string strCRC32=std::to_string(fileCRC32);
    std::string query="update duplicatesview set CRC32='"+strCRC32+"' where Filepath='"+row->at(0)+"'";
    char* charQuery = &query[0];
    db.fireSQLQuery(charQuery,results); 
 }
 db.endTransaction();
}
```

The above code would read the vector dupViewResults(which is already populated by my code)and then update the view and then fire sql query in a transaction.Thanks

Comment: "It is not working" is not a helpful problem description. Your code looks fine.

Comment: __debugbreak() in class dbgrptt.c is being hit in the second join.Not sure why.

Comment: Probably because `method1`, or some function it calls, is being called in an unsafe or incorrect way. Give us enough code to replicate the problem.

Comment: Does the `db` object associate transactions with threads automatically? If not, how does it know which transaction is ending when `endTransaction` is called?

Comment: db object does not know about the threads.I think I am missing here..But how should I make threads know details on which transaction?

Comment: I don't know, it depends what your `db` object is. Maybe each thread should have its own? Maybe the `db` should return a transaction object that's passed to all of its members? Maybe it should inherently associate functions with ongoing transactions based on the thread that calls it. There's a lot of ways to make a thread-safe databaase, but you have to do that or your code will crash.

Comment: Or instead to root cause the issue,can I have two same code methods and then call them?In this case,each thread would have its own transaction correct?

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing your code. Most likely, you need two instances of `db`, one for each thread. But if they just both call into an underlying object that's not thread safe, that won't help very much.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, it sounds like your `db` member is not thread safe. For example, when you call `endTransaction` on it, it has no way to know which transaction to end.

You have three choices, some of which may not work depending on details you haven't provided:

1. Each thread could have its own database object.
2. The database object could return a "transaction" object that subsequent functions take. Each thread could allocate its own transaction object.
3. The database object could associate operations with the thread that calls it, knowing that `endTransaction` ends the transaction started by that same thread.

If you're going to call into a database from multiple threads at the same time, the database must be thread safe.

Comment: Hi David,i found the error.i am receiving it from the method1() when I am trying to add offset to the vector.Error:Vector iterator + offset out of range.